# JBoss Tools 4.1 with Eclipse JavaEE bundle, but why?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss

On the [JBoss Tools website](http://tools.jboss.org/) they recommend explicitly to use Eclipse JavaEE bundle for the Tools. But when I install 4.1.1 (with all checkboxes) on a Standard Eclipse bundle, I have everything what JavaEE bundle has, with the ONLY execption of Mylyn (but therefore additionally Source for JDT and PDE). Or do I have a "missing link" here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We state that Eclipse JavaEE is recommended since then you:

A) have 90% or so of all the required dependencies anyway (faster install)

B) get all the functionalities of Eclipse JavaEE/WTP available to you instead of "just" the ones JBoss Tools explicitly rely on. (more consistent functionallity)